# What is the way to declare a method that apply only specific type of key of object?

Tags: typescript, inferred-type

I have an interface like so:

```js
interface Element {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  relatedElementsIds: string[];
  functionalitiesIds: string[];
}
```

and I want to call to a method that accept only keys that have the type `string[]`.
so called like:

```js
test(element, 'relatedElementsIds'); // Ok
test(element, 'functionalitiesIds'); // Ok
test(element, 'id'); // Error
test(element, 'name'); // Error
```

What is a good way to declare the method without being specific to the current properties of the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interface Element {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  relatedElementsIds: string[];
  functionalitiesIds: string[];
}

declare var element: Element

/**
 * Get union of all values
 */
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

/**
 * If Property is string[] - return this property
 * If Property is not string[] - return never
 */
type Filter<T> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends string[] ? Prop : never
}

/**
 * Get union of all filtered property.
 * Keep in mind that 'relatedElementsIds' | never evaluates to 'relatedElementsIds'
 * This is how you can get rid of never
 */
type GetKeys<T> = Values<Filter<T>>

function test<Obj extends Element, Key extends GetKeys<Obj>>(obj: Obj, key: Key) {

}
test(element, 'relatedElementsIds'); // Ok
test(element, 'functionalitiesIds'); // Ok
test(element, 'id'); // Error
test(element, 'name'); // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsIFsLmQbwFgAoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG4SyQ4cb7GRX2yKBHRxIFDNlxhaASQq0eDZgG0Aum1LIYAVxAIwwAPad0wQxDkKlfJus0BfEiQoQEo4cgBucKMhFS4FSSOODOxGAAngAOKABqcOg6lgA8ACoAfAC8aSoA1hCRRjDIaWrhUbHIAGLA6JBQ6dlEWioAClBG0eQgyAVFJWVUuR1dav4AHpAgCnTK-OoA-KPRVCAQXtAkTsQklSgA4hBgANKFtE1ZCUmptfXQTRnhuvqGJsiQ9CkA8gBGAFaTaazELSAA0yDOkSBuFmR1O5x%20AIyGQAFEYAVQ-v8wf0qFCAJQtbZ7SxgVEBUJgCEAcmEonEoPAVloNIJLGQAHpOchvnlSfQKZgqbSXgZjKZzMBLPJWeyuTy%20QLyZTwcgaZQ2RzuWgoJ0oMqhYFqerODgtQrdfqgA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type StringArrayKeyOf<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as (T[K] extends string[] ? K : never)]: T[K]
}

declare function test(e: Element, key: StringArrayKeyOf<Element>): void
```